# Search-guard plugin of docker ELK stack troubles while connecting to elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin

A few minutes ago I clone `search guard branch` [from here](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk/tree/searchguard) and I does everythink what `README` said.

After `docker-compose up -d` all services are working but `elasticsearch_1` log one error every few secounds:

> elasticsearch_1  | [2018-09-14T08:59:49,614][ERROR][c.f.s.a.BackendRegistry  ] Not yet initialized (you may need to run sgadmin)

After that I run `docker-compose exec -T elasticsearch bin/init_sg.sh`, output:

```
Search Guard Admin v6
Will connect to localhost:9300 ... done
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/search-guard-6/netty-common-4.1.16.Final.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Elasticsearch Version: 6.3.2
Search Guard Version: 6.3.2-23.0
Connected as CN=kirk,OU=client,O=client,L=Test,C=DE
Contacting elasticsearch cluster 'elasticsearch' and wait for YELLOW clusterstate ...
    ERR: Timed out while waiting for a green or yellow cluster state.
    * Try running sgadmin.sh with -icl (but no -cl) and -nhnv (If that works you need to check your clustername as well as hostnames in your TLS certificates)
    * Make also sure that your keystore or PEM certificate is a client certificate (not a node certificate) and configured properly in elasticsearch.yml
    * If this is not working, try running sgadmin.sh with --diagnose and see diagnose trace log file)
    * Add --accept-red-cluster to allow sgadmin to operate on a red cluster.
```

I guess that sgadmin can't connect to elasticsearch cluster but I does everythink what README said.

Any sugestions how to fix this?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already resolve this. Your product, works complitely fine. I had error with index win Kibana which make `elasticsearch cluster` RED status - never YELLOW.

If you want connect your `sgadmin` with `elasticsearch cluster` without waiting for YELLOW status use line: **`--accept-red-cluster`** in `init_sg.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
plugins/search-guard-6/tools/sgadmin.sh \
    -cd config/sg/ \
    -ts config/sg/truststore.jks \
    -ks config/sg/kirk-keystore.jks \
    -nhnv \
    -icl \
    --accept-red-cluster
```

Then everything works fine and Kibana will show you why you have RED status - in my case kibana index problem.